# artifacts in baked normal map(cycles)

Tags: texture-baking, artifacts

trying to bake normal map from high to low poly mesh[image]
result have artifacts
 
1- it not smooth
2- it have some weird colorful areas
[image]

what I did wrong? need help :(

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE. Yo can try to play with the "ray distance" value in the bake panel. The result will depend on the actual distance between the two meshes surfaces and this value.

Comment: Thanks :) with 0.1 ray distance normal map looks much better