# Normal Map Baking Error, UVs are empty

Tags: normal-map

As mentioned, my baked normal map is kind of weird and I don't know what caused it.
I baked normal maps previously, but I'm not a pro.

Appreciate any help!:)[image]

I selected the high-poly mesh first, then the low-poly mesh.
Low poly mesh is unwrapped.

EDIT: Here's the .blend file: [image]

SOLUTION:Turns out the subdivision modifier was too high. After turning it down to 2, the normal map worked!

Comment: That can be similar to this (look at the comments): http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74708/artifacts-in-baked-normal-mapcycles

Comment: Changing the ray distance didn't work out, but thanks for your help!:)

Comment: Second hypothesis, faces normals... are they all to the outside?

Comment: Checked the faces normals, made them all consistent outside. Didn't help, still the same error.
Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: OK, so that may be inner parts of the model? You should consider to upload your file in order we can have a closer look. Use this link to do it http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Alright, uploaded the file.
Check the post description.

The high poly mesh is the same as the low poly one now, had to reduce the size of the file.
Just apply a subsurface modifier and you should be good:)

Thanks for having a look!

Comment: It works here, or at least I don't have the holes showed in the image in your question

Comment: Hmm strange... Care to explain what you did? Any changes, new image?

Comment: Just the following: applied a subdivision (2) to highpoly (as you said), Make meshes to overlap (same position), then select high and low, and click bake

Comment: Alright, somehow messed up wih the subdivision. Thanks for helping me!:D

Comment: If that was because of Subsurf that still looks like ray length for baking was not enough; areas smoothed by Subsurf were too far away from the lowpoly.